# Why jersey repackaged guava?

Tags: jersey, guava

I don't understand why jersey repackaged version of guava should be used.
In which cases should I use the jersey repackaged version of guava instead of using guava directly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you're modifying Jersey itself, you shouldn't use a repackaged dependency: it's part of the internals of Jersey, repackaged specifically to avoid conflicts with user dependencies.